# I have to find out the id of a table cell (non clickable) and based on it verify another row

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have written below code to get the id of a table cell (non clickable) and want to verify another cell of the same row based on it. But below code return empty id.

```
List<WebElement> text=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Google')]"));
   System.out.println(text.size());
    for(WebElement id:text)
        {
           System.out.println(id.getAttribute("id"));
        }
```

Can someone pls share views?

Comment: Here System.out.println(text.size()) returns "9" but  System.out.println(id.getAttribute("id")); returns empty                                                        I want to get the id so that i can operate on that row to verify other columns

Comment: It may be possible the element which exist in the list not contain the id attribute.print the object and check

Comment: can you run the code ths is posted as answer and let me knw wht happen

Comment: nothing is printed as such because value is null for each case :(

Comment: can you paste full class code including the url and all tht stuff ?

Comment: sry, but i cannot. It is a simple page containing table. And, i have to verify a row.

Comment: Would be able to help, without seeing the html. Provide the table's html.

Comment: Thanks Niks for your support. It is working now with the code that have share with some minor modifications related to identifying the td of desired cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my understanding of your web page:-

1. The text 'Google' is present in the td tag.
2. The id attribute you are trying to get is of a tr tag which contains the td tag.

So essentially, the variable "text" in your code contains a list of td tags. When you try to get the id attribute, what you are getting is the id of the column(td tag) not the row(tr tag).

Please try the following code :-

```
//get the table
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Give the xpath of the table"));

//Get all the rows of the table
List rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

//Iterate through the rows
for(WebElement row: rows) {
    //Get the columns in the row
    Webelement columns = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    //Iterate through each column in the row
    for (WebElements column: columns) {
        //Check if the column contains the required text
        if (column.getText().equals("Google")) {
            //Print the id of the row that contains the column with text 'Google'
            System.out.println(row.getAttribute("id");)
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Please let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Thanks lost, above solution works well with little modifications (to make it specific to my requirements)

Comment: glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> text=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Google')]"));
   System.out.println(text.size());
    for(WebElement id:text)
        {
           String value = id.getAttribute("id");
            if(value != null && !value.equals(""))
              {
                 System.out.println(value);
              }
        }
```